# Control the intensity of the flash light in xamain.forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

i am new to xamarin forms. now 'm developing a sample application for making a Torch. i got a nuget for On/Off the flash light. https://github.com/kphillpotts/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Lamp  .  but i like to control the intensity of the flash light. i tried to use the native code but failed to do it. i search the google but cant find it .is there any way i can make it for achieving it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a plugin that implements it. But you can easily extend the lamp plugin.

You could **extend** the interface ILamp like

```
public interface ILamp
{
    ///....
    void TurnOn(float intensity);
}
```

then implement it by copying the `TurnOn` functionality

**iOS**

```
public void TurnOn(float intensity)
{
    var captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.DefaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Video);
    if (captureDevice == null)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("No captureDevice - this won't work on the simulator, try a physical device");
      return;
    }

    NSError error = null;
    captureDevice.LockForConfiguration(out error);
    if (error != null)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine(error);
      captureDevice.UnlockForConfiguration();
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      if (captureDevice.TorchMode != AVCaptureTorchMode.On)
      {
        captureDevice.TorchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.On;
        NSError err;
        captureDevice.SetTorchModeLevel(intensity, out err); // add this line
      }
      captureDevice.UnlockForConfiguration();
    }
}
```

On Android I'm not sure if there is a API to control it. I can't find one. If there is one, just proceed like on iOS.

If the platform has no API, just implement `TurnOn(float intensity)` like

```
public void TurnOn(float intensity)
{
    TurnOn();       
}
```